# Salesforce Professional Edition Options

Tags: sales-cloud

I have a Salesforce Professional Org and I need to be able to weekly update account records with utilization statistics from another app that I have in CSV.

Data Loader is not on my org
tried Inspector and that wont work can find account object
tried work bench but get an API error

HELP!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Professional Edition doesn't include API without purchasing this capability as an add-on.

If you have an Account Executive you can contact them or go through the Sales team.

The editions with and without API access are listed here: [Salesforce editions with API access](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385436&type=1).

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase API access as an add-on for $35/user/month, according to the current [marketing material](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_au/www/documents/pricing/all-add-ons-au.pdf) as of the time of this answer. You can also use the manual [data import wizard](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.import_with_data_import_wizard.htm&language=en_US&type=5), which is built-in and costs nothing to use, with the downside of being, of course, manual.